# What would be the proper way to mark a function only meant for overriding?

Tags: c++

I have a class that is meant to be used as is or inherited by 3rd party software. It has a function `Resize` that might seem attractive and straightforward to an unsuspecting developer but it is only meant to be called from a single internal place with special preparation needed beforehand.

The only reason its a separate function is because it is virtual and to be overriden in case the 3rd party inherited classes need to do things before and after the contents of this function.

Is there any way to mark it available only when overriding? So you couldn't actually go `MyClass.Resize()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options available that offer this level of control. The easiest is to provide a protected virtual member;

```
class MyClass {
protected:
  virtual void Resize(); /* =0*/
};
```

Depending on your requirements, you may want to make it a pure virtual function to force the derived classes to override the function (note; you can still provide an implementation of the function even if it is pure, the derived class needs to explicitly call it to get the default functionality).

Another approach is to provide two other functions that need to be overridden in the base class before and after the call to the `Resize` method, making of the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). This pattern is also used in the standard iostreams library for methods such as `sync()`.

Answer (score 1):

If it should only be called from inheriting classes, mark it protected. I.e:

```
class Base {
public:
  // ...

protected:
  virtual void Resize(...);

private:
  // ...
};
```

This means that only classes that inherit from your class and the class itself can access the function. If your inheriting classes do not/should not call the function directly, but rather only provide an implementation, you can even mark it private, see http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm for a discussion on this.

Comment: This. Literally the purpose of `protected`. Sadly doesn't go all the way, but it's the closest you can get.

Comment: @PreferenceBean: Actually, you can go all the way. Nothing is preventing you from overriding private functions.

Comment: @MikeMB: Does that work? Can you call a `private` `Base::foo` from within `Derived::foo`?

Comment: @PreferenceBean: No. The use case for marking it private is when it is the base that calls the method - the derived class only provides it's implementation.

Comment: @villintehaspam Right, so I don't see how that relates to what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @PreferenceBean: I think that @MikeMB's point is related. Nialls answer has the complete solution spelled out, i.e. if you have a method that you want to allow inheriting classes to provide additional pre and post steps for, there could be pre and post customization points instead. I.e. private `PreResize()` and `PostResize` virtual functions that are called from the non-virtual `Base::Resize()`. Using a single virtual protected method is another option, lazy/pragmatic depending on who you ask.

Comment: @villintehaspam: Yeah that'd be a much better way to do it (albeit arguably not quite as scalably performant if you care about that sort of thing).

Comment: @PreferenceBean: Hence Niall's answer being the accepted one I guess... :)

Comment: @villintehaspam: I actually prefer Colin's but there we go.

Comment: @PreferenceBean: Ah, missed that one - Niall's answer links to "template method pattern" which is essentially that. I see that Colin has actually spelled it out more clearly.

Comment: @villintehaspam: Call it a tie :P

Answer (score 1):

What I sometimes do (to protect the user from themselves) is this:

```
struct MyClass
{
private:
    virtual void PreResize() { }
    virtual void PostResize() { }
    void Resize()
    {
        PreResize();

        //TODO: necessary Resize code here

        PostResize();
    }
};

struct YourClass
{
    virtual void PostResize()
    {
        //TODO: specialized code to run after Resize logic called
    }
};
```

This scheme will absolutely guarantee that necessary code is run when `Resize` is called.

The reason I do this is that it eliminates the need for the user to know whether or not to call `MyClass::Resize` in their overloaded function.

Answer (score 0):

If your function isn't supposed to be called from outside of your class, you can make it private.

C++ fully supports overriding of private member functions:

```
struct Base {
    void Foo() {
        resize();
    }
private:
    virtual void resize() {
        std::cout << "Called Base::resize()" << std::endl;
    }
};


struct Derived : Base { 
private:
    virtual void resize() override {
        std::cout << "Called Derived::resize()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Output:

```
Called Derived::resize()
```

Comment: Right, but this doesn't let you call `Base::resize` from within `Derived::resize`, which seems to be what the OP wanted to do?

Comment: @PreferenceBean: I didn't see that requirement in the OP's question, but on reading it again, I might have missunderstood the problem.